# event when adding element into document

Tags: javascript

Adding new html string into the page:

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<div id="child"></div>';
```

Is there an event that let me know when `child` element is in the document?

I have a function, which return some html codeas a string. And when this html will be added in the document, I need to execute javascript function. I've tried to use inline `onload` event

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<div id="child" onload="console.log(\'ready!\');"></div>';
```

but it does not seem to work.

**UPDATE:**
Probably, I should provide more details about the situation. I have a library function

```
myLibrary.getHtml()
```

In old version, users just call this function and append the result into the document:

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = myLibrary.getHtml();
```

In new version, the result is not a plain html. Now users can interact with it after they append it in the document. So after they append html into the document, I need to go through the result DOM and attach event handlers, hide some elements and other things. That is why, I need to know when they add it in the document and execute a javascript function, which turn plain html into fancy interactive widget.

Comment: Can't you just call the function yourself immediately after setting innerHTML?

Comment: No, the code is a library and users call the library function and append result via innerHTML property. I can not change the way users interact with the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself this way:

```
myLibrary.getHtml = function() {
    var html;
    ...
    var funcName = 'initWidget' + ((Math.random() * 100000) | 0);
    var self = this;
    window[funcName] = function() { self._initWidget(); };
    return html + '<img src="fake-proto://img" onerror="' + funcName + '()"';
}
```

The idea behind the code is that I specify incorrect url for the `src` attribute of the `img` tag and the image triggers error event and call my function. Quite simple :)

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [DOM Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents), but they are still inconsistently implemented across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If i have not misunderstood the question, you can probably get this to work

```
document.getElementById('id').childNodes;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, you could write your own custom event which would call the function you need to call whenever the new html has been added:

```
$('#container').bind('changeHtml', function(e) {
  // Execute the function you need
});
```

And of course instead of just adding the html to the element, you would need to wrap it up in a function which triggers your custom event.  Then all you'd need to do is call this function instead of setting the innerHtml yourself.

```
function addHtml(html) {
  $('#container').innerHTML = html;
  $('#container').trigger('changeHtml');
}
```

Comment: Oh - sorry, just read your comment... if you can't change how people append the html then obviously this won't work...